# Creating ssh key in github

Tags: github

I have a question regarding managing two Github accounts in my machine (office and personal). Whenever I create a repo in personal am I supposed to create a new ssh key(As my office git account username and email are global)? Using windows credentials way I'm prompted to enter the username and password for the first time I do remote push then onwards I need not have to do that for that particular repo. I wanted to try by ssh(to avoid entering my git account credentials for the first time) or can I stick with the windows credential manager way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever I create a repo in personal am I supposed to create a new ssh key(As my office git account username and email are global)?

No: the SSH key remains the same and is used to authenticate you to your personal GitHub account.

You only need to register that key in your ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host perso
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myPersoKey
```

Then, in your local cloned repository:

```
cd /path/to/local/clone
git remote set-url origin perso:<me>/<myrepo>
```

Then a git push will use the SSH URL, with the right perso key.

Comment: In fact your reply confirmed the way i tried after posting the question. Thanks a lot VonC for taking time out to reply to my question.

Comment: VonC im using windows. The above step to set-url is for macbook?. In windows i created  repo internally and just by adding the ssh url from github repo established the connection. Thus, i could push the code into the github repo  without any requirement for entering my github account credentials.

Comment: Yes, those steps would be the same for Windows.